# How to return null in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

Does anyone help me to solve the "Days Of The Week Exercise" in JavaScript?
I searched MDN and tried many times as much as I can, but I still don't get what the null is, and how to use null.

if the argument(num) is less than 1 or greater than 7, the function should return null.

[image: Days Of The Week Exercise]

```
const days = ['Monday','Tuesyday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'];

let returnDay = (num) => {
    if (1 <= num <= 7) {
        return (days[num -1]);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    
};

returnDay(1); // Monday
returnDay(7); // Sunday
returnDay(4); // Thursday
returnDay(0); // null
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please paste your code into your question :)

Comment: Well the issue isnt `return null;` as that is valid, null is just a normal value with a few weird evaluation properties

Comment: I'm really sorry for the inconvenience.
I pasted a screenshot image, so I thought it is enough. But, I'm gonna paste my code directly for the future question!!

Comment: Wait - your screenshot and code differs - does the last function return `undefined` or `null`?

Comment: the returnDay(0); has to be null, but the code I pasted results 'undefined'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1 <= num <= 7` does not do what you think it does. In JavaScript, binary operators are evaluated from left to right. So `1 <= num <= 7` is really `(1 <= num) <= 7`, which is either `true <= 7` or `false <= 7` (depending on what `num` is). Either way, it will evaluate to `true`, but don’t ask me why, because you really shouldn’t compare booleans with numbers anyway. Since the condition is always `true`, the `else` branch is never executed, so you never get `null`.

I think what you want to write is:

```
if (1 <= num && num <= 7) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Furthermore, remember that array indices start with `0`. In your example, `days[1]` would be `'Tuesday'`, not `'Monday'`.

Comment: I tried to change
(1 <= num <= 7)
to
(1 <= num && num <= 7)
and it worked just what I wanted!!!
Thank you for your help!!! XD

Comment: @natsu_0 You're very welcome. Be sure to read the explanation and understand *why* it works. It will help you become a better programmer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer helps you :)

```js
const days = ['Monday', 'Tuesyday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

const returnDay = (num) => {
  const day = num - 1;
  if (days[day]) { // since you passing 0 there is no such element in the array at index -1,
                  //so if statement essentially evaluates to false and returning null right away;
    return days[day];
  }
  return null;
};

console.log(returnDay(1)); // Monday
console.log(returnDay(7)); // Sunday
console.log(returnDay(4)); // Thursday
console.log(returnDay(0)); // null
```

Comment: I didn't think of using "days[day]" for the if statement...
Your answer helped me a lot to find a new way of writing!!!
Thank you for your help!!